# Need clarification of SQL Code to retrieve sales count for consecutive months to be displayed along with employee id

Tags: sql, sql-server, postgresql

My code:

```
select 
   employeeid,
   count( 
      select orderid 
      from orders 
      where orderdate between '1996-07-01' and '1996-07-31';
    ) as JUL_Sales  
from orders 
group by employeeid;
```

Required output is below:

[image]

Comment: "Need Clarification" isn't a question. What are you asking, and what is the problem with what you have? Why have you tagged 2 different RDBMS? What one are you *actually* using?

Comment: Also, you have a wayward `;` in the middle of your statement. I'm guessing this is a typographical error question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the SQL Server code :

```
select 
   employeeid,
   SUM(IIF(orderdate between '1996-07-01' and '1996-07-31', 1, 0)) as JUL_Sales 
from orders 
group by employeeid;
```

Answer (score 0):

In Postgres you can use the standard `filter()` operator:

```
select employeeid,
       count(*) filter (where orderdate between '1996-07-01' and '1996-07-31') as JUL_Sales  
from orders 
group by employeeid;
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for reply guys